# As soon as the interpolated data changes apply a settimeout in angular7

Tags: angular

To remove the element being displayed when it has a particular value

I tried with checking the incoming message(the incoming message changes from a previous value to a new one) and applied timeout to the new message but there is time difference between the message coming in and being displayed on screen, so this approach is not working

```
message: any;
timeOutMessg = [
    'Floor plan uploaded successfully'
]

constructor(private alertService: AlertService,
             private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.alertService.getMessage().subscribe(message 
 => {
        this.message = message;
        console.log(this.message)
        if(this.timeOutMessg.includes(this.message.text)){
        setTimeout(() => { this.message = false}, 5000);
        }

    });
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log('afterviewinit');
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}

<div 
*ngIf="message" 
[ngClass]="{ 'alert': message, 'alert--success': message.type === 
    'success', 'alert--danger': message.type === 'error' }"
 >
{{message.text}}
 </div>
```

I want to apply a settimeout whenever the view has a particular string and I am not aware of when that message will come so will have to check with the particular string value , once the value renders on screen apply timeout to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    if(this.timeOutMessg.includes(this.message && this.message.text)){
        setTimeout(() => { this.message = false}, 3000);
        }
}
```

Lifecycle hooks are a known thing.